# Django no me muestra los labels y los widgets

Tags: python-3.x, django

Hola estoy arrancando a programar en Django. Venia bien hasta que me trabe con el tema de los formularios. Lo que quiero hacer es un formulario para insertar request de acceso a la base de datos, para que después sean procesadas.
Aca abajo les pego mis lineas de código y mi resultado que no es el deseado ojala me puedan ayudar.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from apps.crudRequestAccess.models import RequestUser
from apps.crudRequestAccess.forms import RequestAccessForm
# Create your views here.


class RequestCreate(CreateView):
    model = RequestUser()
    form_class = RequestAccessForm
    template_name = 'crudRequestAccess/request_form.html'
```

request_form.py

```
{%  extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            {% block main-content %}
                <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </form>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm">
            {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from apps.crudRequestAccess.models import RequestUser


class RequestAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestUser
        fields = "__all__"

        labels = {
            'First_Name': 'First Name',
            'Last_Name': 'Last Name',
            'Enterprise_Id': 'EnterpriseId',
            'Email': 'Email',
            'Profile': 'Profile',
            'Environment': 'Environment',
            'Approved_By': 'Approved By',
            'Roll_Off': 'Roll Off Date:',
            'Public_Group': 'Public Group',
            'Permission_Set_Licence': 'Permission Set Licence',
            'Permissions_Set': 'Permissions Set',
            'Comments': 'Comments',
            'Status': 'Status',
            'Rejected_By': 'Rejected By',
            'Create_Date': 'Create Date',
            'Create_By': 'Create By',
            'Last_Modify': 'Last Modify',
            'Last_Modify_By': 'Last Modify By'
        }

        widgets = {
            'First_Name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Last_Name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Enterprise_Id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Profile': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Environment': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Approved_By': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Roll_Off': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Public_Group': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Permission_Set_Licence': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Permissions_Set': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Comments': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Status': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Rejected_By': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Create_Date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Create_By': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Last_Modify': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Last_Modify_By': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class RequestUser(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Last_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Enterprise_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=75),
    Profile = models.TextField(max_length=50),
    Environment = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Approved_By = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Roll_Off = models.DateField(),
    Public_Group = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='None'),
    Permission_Set_Licence = models.TextField(max_length=100),
    Permissions_Set = models.TextField(max_length=100),
    Comments = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="New", editable=False),
    Rejected_By = models.CharField(max_length=15, editable=False, blank=True),
    Create_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, editable=False),
    Create_By = models.TextField(max_length=50),
    Last_Modify = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, editable=False),
    Last_Modify_By = models.CharField(max_length=15, editable=False, blank=True)


class PublicGroup(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    GroupsAssociated = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class Profile(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    ProfileName = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    IdProfile = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class PermissionsSet(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class PermissionSetLicence(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class PermissionSetLicenceAssignment(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Id_User = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class PermissionSetAssignment(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Id_User = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False),
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)


class Approve(models.Model):
    #en lugar de poner uno individual poner el grupo del equipo
    Enterprise_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Team = models.CharField(max_length=50),


# Data Model Exception List
class ExceptionList(models.Model):
    Enterprise_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Profile = models.TextField(max_length=50),
    Public_Group = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='None'),
    Comments = models.TextField(max_length=200),
    Approved_By = models.CharField(max_length=50)


# Data Model TestId
class TestId(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Last_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Enterprise_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=75),
    Profile = models.TextField(max_length=50),
    Public_Group = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='None'),
    Permission_Set_Licence = models.TextField(max_length=100),
    Permissions_Set = models.TextField(max_length=100),


# Users that SpringCM Team request for each integration
class SpringCM(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Last_Name = models.TextField(max_length=15),
    Enterprise_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=75),
    Profile = models.TextField(max_length=50),
    Public_Group = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='None'),
    Permission_Set_Licence = models.TextField(max_length=100),
    Permissions_Set = models.TextField(max_length=100),
```

me falto mostrar el resultado, es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SOes. Porfavor, has el [tour]. Considera leer el articulo [ask] y despues borra la respuesta que has publicado y ve a [edit] tu pregunta para agregar tu imagen. Tambien, parece que el modelo se queda a la mitad, te ha faltado colocar algo?

Comment: Hola, recuerda que puedes realizar ediciones a la pregunta para agregar más información mediante la opción "editar" @user1145543

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en tu template realizes un for para imprimir cada campo de tu formulario:

```
{% for row in form %}
    <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %} has-error {% endif %}"> <!-- con la clase has-error podemos hacer visualizar al usuario cuando algo anda mal -->
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.html_name }}"> <!-- field.html_name imprime el nombre que django le da al campo -->
            {% if field.field.required %}<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-red"></i> {% endif %}{{ field.label_tag }} <!-- .label_tag es el valor del label que le diste en forms.py -->
        </label>
        {{ field }} <!-- aqui imprimimos el campo -->
        <p class="help-block">{{ field.errors.as_text }} {{ field.field.css_classes }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Espero esto te pueda servir. De esta manera es mas facil manipular tu formulario y darle los estilos que mas te convengan/gusten.
Puedes comunicarme cual es el resultado para llegar a la solucion optima.